# Is there a limit to the Maximum size of data returned of queries to the Azure App Insights API?

Tags: azure, powerbi, botframework, azure-application-insights

I hope someone can help me.

I currently have an architecture where the telemetry data generated by a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework is send into a ***Azure App Insights resource*** and from then extracted from a ***PowerBI resource***

I am currently receiving an error from the PowerBI side due to problems extracting the event data in the query to Azure App Insights.

400 (bad request)
[https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/apps/{private-key-azure-app-insights}/query?query=customEvents%0A%7C%20project%20%0AActivityId%20%3D%20customDimens..](https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/apps/%7Bprivate-key-azure-app-insights%7D/query?query=customEvents%0A%7C%20project%20%0AActivityId%20%3D%20customDimens..).

The strange thing is that this error started at a seemingly random time in prod and when I try to change the keys of the azure app insights resource for two active and different bots and two different environments I have the following result:

| - | Bot 1 | Bot 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| env Prod | error querys to AAI | error querys to AAI |
| env QA | successful integration | successful integration |

Are there limits to the volume of data extracted from an Azure App Insights resource using queries to his API?, or are there any settings in the portal that make it impossible to query AAI API?

Answer (score 0):

When I check I receive from Azure Log Analytics

{"message": "Response size too large"}

from [Azure Monitor service limits for Query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits#la-query-api).

[image]